# Inappropriate ioctl for device serial-master/src/unix.cpp

Tags: c++, raspbian, ioctl

I use the **wjwwood serial-master** library to manage serial ports on my Raspberry Pi under Linux.
Using the /dev/ttyAMA0 serial port 
It works fine in Raspbian 9.4, but in Raspbian 8.0 I receive the following error

> "Inappropriate ioctl for device" file /serial-master/src/unix.cpp, line 488

The line is:

````cpp
size_t
Serial::SerialImpl::available ()
{
  if (!is_open_) {
    return 0;
  }
  int count = 0;

  if (-1 == ioctl (fd_, TIOCINQ, &count)) {
      THROW (IOException, errno);
  } else {
      return static_cast<size_t> (count);
  }
}
```cpp


<https://github.com/wjwwood/serial>
````

Comment: Please create an MCVE. Add `main()` function, `open()` calls, relevant `#include`s and all the smallest possible code needed to reproduce the problem. `file /serial-master/src/unix.cpp` this is a file, it has no "input buffer".

Comment: The [man-page](https://linux.die.net/man/4/tty_ioctl) I found tells that FIONREAD should do the same. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks . But with FIONREAD the error remains

Comment: Serial object is for serial files i presume. `/serial-master/src/unix.cpp` is a normal file, you can't do operations on normal files like you would on sockets for exampe. Is this http://wjwwood.io/serial/doc/1.1.0/classserial_1_1serial_1_1_serial_1_1_serial_impl.html ?

Comment: Yes .  This is the library wjwwood